# Get key of biggest-sum list in a Dictionary of Lists

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

I have a dictionary with keys of integers and values of lists.

```
dict = {1: [0.1, 0.4, 0.05, 0.25], 3: [1, 8, 0.2, 3], 29: [2, 0, 1, 7]}
```

I want to get

```
largest_k = 3 # as its list sums to 12.2
```

I have tried

```
for n in dict.keys():
    d[n] = sum(dict[n])
largest_k = max(d, key=d.get)
```

And I get

```
d = {1: 0.8, 3: 12.2, 29: 10}
largest_k = 3
```

as intended but it's cumbersome (and creates a new dictionary).

How do I find largest_k without resorting to a new dictionary or modifying the original dictionary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a more detailed sorting key, and try the `max` function instead (since you only want the largest one):

```
>>> dct = {1: [0.1, 0.4, 0.05, 0.25], 3: [1, 8, 0.2, 3], 29: [2, 0, 1, 7]}
>>> max(dct.items(), key=lambda x: sum(x[1]))[0]
3
```

And don't use `dict` as a name, as it's already in use by the `dict` built-in function.

Comment: Slightly simpler: `max(dct, key=lambda x: sum(dct[x]))`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
>>> my_dict = {1: [0.1, 0.4, 0.05, 0.25], 3: [1, 8, 0.2, 3], 29: [2, 0, 1, 7]}
>>> max(my_dict.items(), key=lambda x: sum(x[1]))
(3, [1, 8, 0.20000000000000001, 3])
```